# Outlook - moving email using a macro does not preserve the receipt date

Tags: vba, outlook

While using a macro in outlook to move an email into a subfolder, the receipt date is not preserved.

Does anyone has an idea on how to avoid that?

Comment: Please post your code. Usually the date is unaffected by moving a message.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the macro changes the ModifiedTime parameter which is actually right. What is wrong is that outlook in the folder view does -in column Receveid- not show the ReceivedTime, but the ModifiedTime. I also found that the Modified Column (normally not visible) contains the actual RecievedTime. So a remedy is to keep the macro as is, but add (right mouse button on the columns in a folder view) the Modified column to the view and optionally removed the Received column. You will find Modified in the "All Post fields" section.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer.. but here is some code that replicates the problem.  Can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.  Quite a few people asking the question though.

```
Sub MoveToFolder(objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
  'On Error Resume Next
  If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "This folder doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID FOLDER"
  End If

  If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
  For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
      If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
          If objItem.Class = olMail Then
              objItem.Move objFolder
          End If
      End If
  Next

  Set objItem = Nothing
  Set objFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033556/outlook-2003-vba-movin-e-mails-without-changing-the-date