# Outlook 2003/VBA Movin E-Mails without changing the date

Tags: email, vba, outlook

I use a macro in outlook 2003 to move selected emails to a specific folder. The moving works, but unfortunately the received date is overwritten to the current time.
Any idea on how to prevent this.

I use this code:

```
Sub verschiebenInOrdner()

On Error Resume Next

    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace, objItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.Item("2009").Folders.Item("In")

    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "This folder doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID FOLDER"
    End If

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                objItem.UnRead = False
                objItem.Move objFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks to the help of 76mel I came up with this:

```
    Sub verschiebenInArchiv()

Dim Session As Redemption.rDOSession
Dim objFolder As Redemption.RDOFolder
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objItem2 As Redemption.RDOMail

Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")

Session.Logon

Set objFolder = Session.Stores.Item("2009").IPMRootFolder.Folders("In")

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set objItem2 = Session.GetMessageFromID(objItem.EntryID, Session.Stores.DefaultStore.EntryID)
    objItem2.Move objFolder
Next

End Sub
```

This works when I am in my Inbox. Does anybody know how I can set the Store-ID in GetMessageFromID to the ID of the store in which my selection is made?

Edit: Thanks 76mel, I am using objItem.Parent.StoreID now to get the current StoreID.

Comment: I doesn't change the date for me using Outlook 2003 (11.8118.8132) SP2

Comment: As others have stated, this shouldn't change the date. Maybe your actual code is slightly different from what you quoted here?

Comment: are you running any other code that would change the date ?

Comment: that is the actual code. searching the internet some people report this problem while others report that they don't have this problem. Outlook 2003 SP3 here.

Comment: @76mel: no that is the only code i use in outlook

Comment: get the storeid from the selected Item parent folder StoreID property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right there has been a few reports around the net saying it doesn’t work.

It would seem that VB6 doesn’t bubble up an error :( . I think that the way to tackle this would be to use CDO or the defacto 3rd party lib "Redemption". To do the actual move in the background.

M

Update: 
Try something like this .. I dont have VB on may machine so haven't tested it
But you will get the idea.

```
Sub verschiebenInOrdner()

On Error Resume Next


    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objRDOSession As Redemption.RDOSession
    Dim objRDOFolder As Redemption.RDOFolder
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objRDOMail As Redemption.RDOMail


    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objRDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    objRDOSession.MAPIOBJECT = objNS.MAPIOBJECT  'or Logon

    Set objRDOFolder = Session.GetFolderFromPath("<YOUR PATH>")
    ' do your validation for folder and selection



    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objItem.Class = olMail Then
              Set objRDOMail = objRDOSession.GetMessageFromID(objItem.EntryID)
              objRDOMail.UnRead = False
              objRDOMail.Move objRDOFolder

            End If
        End If
    Next



    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objRDOMail = Nothing
    Set objRDOFolder = Nothing
    Set objRDOSession = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried copying the mail to a Redemption.SafeMailItem and move this afterwards, but it still overwrites the ReceivedTime.

Comment: Ok Safemail work a the same level as the OOM so probably experience the same problem. I would use RDO if you are using Redemption.
Create a RDOSession >Logon >grab your folder using GetFolderFromPath and the use the entryids from you selection to get RDOMail via the session using GetMessageFromID. Then do you move on the RDOMail.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one little detail. Please see my edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change the date for me in Outlook 2003 either.  If it is a continuing problem for you I would try to get the date of the item and overwrite it after transferring it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : in the sub folder you move the email to, simply add a column for the field "date created" instead of "received date" and sort using this field... job done !

Reef